# KWP OBD2 ECU Target Address

Tags: obd-ii, pid

When communicating with an ECU via the OBD2 port using the CAN protocol, we have a well known address $7DF. Irrespective of the make and model of the car this address can be used to read MODE 1 information.

When using the K Line and KWP protocol, it seems there are no WELL KNOWN addresses we can target for the ECU? I have tried to go through the ISO 9141 specification and it does not mention any standard address, just Manufacturer defined.

I want to know if there is a standard Target address for ECU that can be used across the board with about 70-80% success when using the K-Line / KWP protocol? It seems strange to write some code which will scan all possible addresses because it works with any car.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the broadcast headers I know of:

- 11-bit CAN: `0x7DF`
- 29-bit CAN: `0x18DB33F1`
- KWP: `0x81F110`
- J1850 PWM: `0x616AF1`
- J1850 VPWM: `0x686AF1`
- ISO9141-2: `0x486B10`

These headers are taken with an OBD2 simulator that features all protocols and two ELM327 adapters, one that always matched the simulator mode and monitoring with `ATMA`, the other one querying the auto detection via `ATSP0` and `0100`.